# Sort fields in rendered JSON

Tags: spray-json

Using Spray JSON, how can I render the objects with their fields alphanumerically sorted?

My objective is to get sorted output so that I can use text-only diff tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the latest version of spray-json there is now a `sortedPrint` method for this: https://github.com/spray/spray-json/pull/164